# Calling a variable into another method in java

Tags: java

Does anyone know how to call a variable into another method? Doing an assignment for school and really struggling. (Variable that I want to call is arrayOfEarth by the way.)

```
 public static void readDataArray(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.xyz")));
    int rows = 2500000;
    int columns = 3;

    double[][] arrayOfEarth = new double[rows][columns];
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        for (int a = 0; a < arrayOfEarth.length; a++) {
            String[] line = input.nextLine().trim().split("/t ");
            for (int b = 0; b < line.length; b++) {
                arrayOfEarth[a][b] = Double.parseDouble(line[b]);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayOfEarth));
}

public static List<Double> CoordinatesAbove(double altitude) {
    List<Double> CoordinatesAbove = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int c = 0; c < arrayOfEarth.length; c++) {
        CoordinatesAbove.add(arrayOfEarth[c][2]);
    }
    CoordinatesAbove.removeIf(d -> d < altitude);
    return CoordinatesAbove;
}
```

Comment: You don't "call" a variable; you "call" a method.

Comment: Just make readDataArray return arrayOfEarth and call it in method CoordinatesAbove to get the data.

Comment: You can always pass arrayOfEarth as a parameter to other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just move it to the class level and make it static (otherwise the static method can't use it)

```
private static double[][] arrayOfEarth;

public static void readDataArray(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.xyz")));
    int rows = 2500000;
    int columns = 3;

    arrayOfEarth = new double[rows][columns];
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        for (int a = 0; a < arrayOfEarth.length; a++) {
            String[] line = input.nextLine().trim().split("/t ");
            for (int b = 0; b < line.length; b++) {
                arrayOfEarth[a][b] = Double.parseDouble(line[b]);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayOfEarth));
}

public static List<Double> CoordinatesAbove(double altitude) {
    List<Double> CoordinatesAbove = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int c = 0; c < arrayOfEarth.length; c++) {
        CoordinatesAbove.add(arrayOfEarth[c][2]);
    }
    CoordinatesAbove.removeIf(d -> d < altitude);
    return CoordinatesAbove;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `readDataArray` method return the value to the caller, and have whoever is calling the `CoordinatesAbove` method pass the value to it.

To return the value and to accept it as a parameter:

```
public static double[][] readDataArray(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
   ...
   System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayOfEarth));
   return arrayOfEarth;
}

public static List<Double> CoordinatesAbove(double altitude, double[][] arrayOfEarth) {
   ...
}
```

To capture the return value of `readDataArray` and to pass it to `CoordinatesAbove`:

```
double[][] arrayOfEarth = readDataArray(...)
List<Double> list = CoordinatesAbove(altitude, arrayOfEarth);
```

It is arguably better to make the flow of information explicit like this, than hiding the flow by writing the results to a common global variable in one method and reading the variable in the other.